# Close div by clicking outside using fadeToggle

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

I'm using `fadeToggle` to open/close a `div`. How can I close the `div` by clicking anywhere outside?

I've tried the following:

```
var dropDown = jQuery('.dropdown-menu');

jQuery('.menu-nav').click(function () { 
    dropDown.fadeToggle('fast');
});

jQuery('div:not(.menu-nav, .dropdown-menu)').click(function () { 
    dropDown.fadeOut('fast');
});
```

What happens is that the `div` opens and closes immediately. Is this even possible with `fadeToggle`?

Comment: Use fadeIn instead of fadeToggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an event handler to the `click` event on the `document`.  When a click occurs check the `target` to determine if either the `.dropdown-menu` or `.menu-nav` was clicked.  If not, then hide the menu.

```
var dropDown = jQuery('.dropdown-menu');

jQuery('.menu-nav').click(
    function (e) { 
        dropDown.fadeToggle('fast');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);

 jQuery('div:not(.menu-nav, .dropdown-menu)').click(
    function (e) { 
        dropDown.fadeOut('fast');
        e.preventDefault();
    }
);

$(document).on("click", function(e){
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if(!$target.is(".menu-nav") && !$target.is(".dropdown-menu")){
        dropDown.fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/UJNd5/

Answer (score 1):

This quite a common requirement. You want to bind a `click` event to the document, then see if that click event's `target` is inside your menu or not, in this case using `.closest()`:

```
var dropDown = jQuery('.dropdown-menu');

// Show the menu
jQuery('.menu-nav').click(function () { 
    dropDown.fadeIn('fast');
});

// Hide the menu
jQuery(document).click(function (e) { 
    if(!jQuery(e.target).closest('.menu-nav').length || !jQuery(e.target).hasClass('dropdown-menu') {
        dropDown.fadeOut('fast');
    }
});
```